# How to fix "WARNING: pystan : MSVC compiler is not supported" while installing fbprophet on Windows?

Tags: python, facebook-prophet, pystan

While trying to install kats on Windows, it is requiring that fbprophet is installed.

This is resulting in the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
  Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py)  error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
INFO: pystan: COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW..
WARNING: pystan : MSVC compiler is not supported"...
```

**Error:**

```
command: 'C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zc4_euql\\fbprophet_baec72f7c19845aaa3050620413adc98\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zc4_euql\\fbprophet_baec72f7c19845aaa3050620413adc98\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gaz4xgyk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\Include\fbprophet'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zc4_euql\fbprophet_baec72f7c19845aaa3050620413adc98\
    Complete output (284 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
    INFO:pystan:COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
    WARNING:pystan:MSVC compiler is not supported
    stanfit4anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9_1451489351938419874.cpp
    C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/meta/seq_view.hpp(145): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(19): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
            [
                Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
            ]
    C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\katfinal\lib\site-packages\pystan\stan\lib\stan_math\stan/math/prim/mat/fun/multiply_lower_tri_self_transpose.hpp(27): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Eigen::EigenBase<Derived>::Index' to 'int', possible loss of data
            with
```

Comment: I see INFO and WARNING, no errors

Comment: Is it _actually_ failing to install? The error is related to pystan. Have you checked this? Seems you need WSL2: https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#is-windows-supported

Comment: There is already the same question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706800/logger-warningmsvc-is-not-supported-error-when-installing-pystan-on-windows